# Hats missing in "Profile" tab when the About Me is blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, meta, winter-bash-2014

Normally, there is "hats" link under "last seen" field in the Profile tab here on MSE. However, when the About Me is blank, there is no "hats" link.

[Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/244519/sompuperoo?tab=profile):

> [image]

When switching to the Activity tab (and on other sites) it is there.

Hats are also available when clicking the avatar, but it's not really intuitive.

Comment: @rene eh, hopefully before that! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed now. I missed that the profile is entirely different when there's no "About me" text.